# iscsi Disk not showing up in /dev/disk/by-path

Tags: unix, iscsi

```
I was able to successfully log into an ISCSI target by command

        command:sudo iscsiadm --mode node --targetname iqn.2010-06.com.XXXX-a215 --portal 10.X.X.X:3260, 1 --login
        output: Logging in to [iface: default, target:iqn.2010-06.com.XXXX-a215, portal: 10.X.X.X,3260] (multiple)
    Login to [iface: default, target:iqn.2010-06.com.XXXX-a215, portal: 10.X.X.X,3260] successful.
```

But when I perform ls -lh /dev/disk/by-path I am not able to find a device corresponding to the above-added target.

when I do iscsiadm -m session -P 3

```
Target: iqn.2010-06.com.XXX-a216 (non-flash)
    Current Portal: X.X.X.X:3260,1
    Persistent Portal: X.X.X.X:3260,1
        **********
        Interface:
        **********
        Iface Name: default
        Iface Transport: tcp
        Iface Initiatorname: iqn.1994-05.com.redhat:6da67798e2
        Iface IPaddress: X.X.X.X
        Iface HWaddress: <empty>
        Iface Netdev: <empty>
        SID: 1
        iSCSI Connection State: Unknown
        iSCSI Session State: LOGGED_IN
        Internal iscsid Session State: Unknown
        *********
        Timeouts:
        *********
        Recovery Timeout: 120
        Target Reset Timeout: 30
        LUN Reset Timeout: 30
        Abort Timeout: 15
        *****
        CHAP:
        *****
        username: <empty>
        password: ********
        username_in: <empty>
        password_in: ********
        ************************
        Negotiated iSCSI params:
        ************************
        HeaderDigest: None
        DataDigest: None
        MaxRecvDataSegmentLength: 262144
        MaxXmitDataSegmentLength: 1048576
        FirstBurstLength: 262144
        MaxBurstLength: 16776192
        ImmediateData: Yes
        InitialR2T: Yes
        MaxOutstandingR2T: 1
        ************************
        Attached SCSI devices:
        ************************
        Host Number: 3  State: running
        scsi3 Channel 00 Id 0 Lun: 0
            Attached scsi disk sdb      State: running
Target: **iqn.2010-06.com.XXX-a215** (non-flash)
    Current Portal: X.X.X.X:3260,1
    Persistent Portal: X.X.X.X:3260,1
        **********
        Interface:
        **********
        Iface Name: default
        Iface Transport: tcp
        Iface Initiatorname: iqn.1994-05.com.redhat:6da67798e2
        Iface IPaddress: 10.15.235.74
        Iface HWaddress: <empty>
        Iface Netdev: <empty>
        SID: 4
```

a216 is able to show as sdb,a215 is not shown and the information about a215 when I did iscsiadm -m session -P 3 is pretty low.what does this mean?

Comment: any one aware of this issue?.

Comment: You must be showing just a portion of the output from "iscsciadm -m session -P3"?

Comment: Can you get ride of target a215 and just try to connect to a216? You can use debug mode for iscsiadm to get more information, and debug mode for iscsid as well.